# Kazam doesn't work on ubuntu 17.10 what's the next best thing?

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast

I am looking for a screen recorder that uses a little resources as possible and is able to record full-screen 3D gaming.

As far as I know Kazam was good for that but unfortunately it is not compatible for my version of ubuntu and checking its update history (last update 2014) I doubt it will be anytime soon....

So what should I try instead?

I use the latest Mesa drivers (17.3) Padoka and Oibaf ppa (yes I know... but it works find for me :P ) I have an AMD FX 8350 16GB ram and a RX 580 8GB.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 now uses GNOME, which supposedly can [make a screencast](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en) readily.

Comment: Use Xorg when logging in to Ubuntu. Kazam works like charm on my 17.10, given that I am in Xorg.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know [OBS studio](https://obsproject.com/) is the best screen recorder for Ubuntu.

But for Ubuntu 17.10 there are some issues with OBS studio in `Wayland display server`. So if you are ready to switch to `Xorg`, OBS would be a nice choice for screen recording.

You can install OBS studio from the below commands.

Install ffmpeg

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

After installing FFmpeg, install OBS Studio using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

Answer (score 0):

Green Recorder works on both Wayland and Xorg and thus works fine on 17.10
https://github.com/foss-project/green-recorder